# What controllers are supported through Big Picture Mode?

Tags: steam, controllers

For Big Picture Mode, they always advertise on the game's Steam page that it supports full-controller or partial-controller. Next to that they show a picture of the [Logitech F710](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/wireless-gamepad-f710). I know that they do support the [Xbox 360 controller for Windows](http://support.xbox.com/en-GB/games/xbox-controller-for-windows-info).

Are these the only controllers that Steam supports or are there more?

Answer (score 9):

Officially, [Steam Support](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5006-ASLN-3202) states support for the following.

> Currently, Big Picture supports the Xbox 360 Wireless Controller for Windows, the Xbox 360 Wired Controller, and the Logitech Wireless Gamepad F710.

In addition, you can infer support for a variety of third party gamepads that offer similar button layouts and drivers -  for instance, any third party Xbox compatible gamepads should work just fine.

With the use of third party drivers like [MotioninJoy](http://www.motioninjoy.com), a variety of other options are usable as well, though unsupported.